# Iterate through List<String> using JSF 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this java code.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("Hello");
myList.add("World");
```

I need to loop through the list to display those values in a webpage. I thought of using a dataTable but I don't know how to retrieve each entry on the list.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Java EE 6 tutorial has a section which lists all available components and how they are to be used: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-repeat.html):

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.myList}" var="value">
    #{value} <br />
</ui:repeat>
```

If you're not sure if you should use `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>`, you can check an example that mkyong provides here: [JSF 2 repeat tag example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-repeat-tag-example/)

In short: `<h:dataTable>` renders a `<table>` HTML component, while `<ui:repeat>` gives you the flexibility to choose how to display the data.

Comment: Simple, concise, to the point, and correct. Thanks for your help, sir!