# Show String with multiple colors

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF outputText label like this

```
  <h:outputText value="#{message}" style="#{Bean.getCSS(message)}" />
```

Now I want to show this String message in multiple colors. For example, If my message is "Hello World" which is one String, I want to show 'Hello' in Red color and 'World' in green color.

In my Bean Class I wrote method like this but don't how to implement this.

```
 public String getCSS ( Srtring message ) {
     String css="";
     return css;
 }
```

Comment: did you thought to put words in differents <span> tags and put different styles in spans?

Comment: Uh, JSF is just a HTML code generator. First figure out which HTML code exactly you'd like to end up with, and then figure out the JSF code necessary to generate exactly that HTML output. If you already can't figure out the desired HTML output, then you don't have a JSF problem at all. Reformulate your question if necessary.

Comment: Using JSF to generate inline css style seems odd to me.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can add a String variable in your bean with name of desired CSS class and set it from the `getCSS` method. Then in your `<h:outputText/>` add the `styleClass` tag with this variable.

Comment: @ForguesR: Care to elborate why? Any other way to do it then? Question seems clear to me

Comment: @Kukeltje Question is crystal clear.  AFAIK short answer is "a pure css is not possible".  Other way of doing it depends of what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: OP wants to achieve this: _"Now I want to show this String message in multiple colors."_. Pure CSS solution was not required. Solution: Split the string into strings and for each string define the css (create a . Then put them in a list and in the xhtml iterate over the list and create spans with the corresponding css. Something like in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150728/iterate-through-liststring-using-jsf-2. All basic things, just combine them...

Comment: @hamza-don: That is what is exactly already in the question, but even in some way more generic