# How to create multiple anchor tag and fetch href value from database dynamically in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I want to create a dynamic anchor tag. Let's say I have a database and I want to use them.

Example:
Before

```html
<a href="page1.xhtml">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.xhtml">Page 2</a>
<a href="page3.xhtml">Page 3</a>
```

It should be something like this
--After--

```html
<a href="{Value from database}">{Value from database}</a>
```

```html
<a href="#{appRoot}/{linkOpsBean.srcNameList[0]}">#{linkOpsBean.srcNameList[0]}</a>
```

Comment: I want to create multiple anchor tags with dynamic href values. I don't want to use hard-coded values.

Comment: Get the outcomes from a bean. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150728/iterate-through-liststring-using-jsf-2

Comment: Hey!!
Getting values like this:
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@2246fe0d
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@64b15db7
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@63b0796e
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@53ed9818
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@46ceb2fe
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@287c1375
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@48e7641d
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@77f50841
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@441f0d03
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@c30594e
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@7f040359
javax.faces.model.SelectItem@20ecbbf8

How to convert it to String?

Comment: Thank you so much, Jasper!!
Your solution helped me a lot! 
Fixed the above issue too. I was using ArrayList<SelectItem> srcNameList; converted it to ArrayList<String> srcNameList;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me!

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{Bean.srcNameList}" var="value">
   <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#{value}">#{value}</a></li>
</ui:repeat>
```